# Does $\cos(z)=\sqrt{2}$ have complex solutions?

Tags: complex-analysis

I have to show whether $cos(z)=\sqrt{2}$ has any real or complex solutions. I know it has no real solutions since $-1\leq \cos(x)\leq 1$ for $x\in \mathbb{R}$. But how can I show that it has complex solutions? Working through using the identity $\cos(z)=\frac{e^{iz}+e^{-iz}}{2}$, I found that $z=\frac{ln(\sqrt{2}\pm 1)}{i}+2\pi k$ where $k\in \mathbb{Z}$. Can anybody confirm this solution or show me how to further simplify my result?

Comment: I think you can use $\cos(z) = \frac{z+z^{-1}}{2}$ for $z\in \mathbb{C}$!

Comment: Hint: Think in terms of the _hyperbolic_ cosine, and its relation to the trigonometric cosine.

Comment: @Semiclassical I'm not very familiar with hyperbolic trig functions. Can you tell me how cosh relates to cos?

Comment: @Euler_Salter: this is very far away from being true. For $z= \pi /2$  your equation gives $ \pi^2=-4$ !

Comment: By definition, $\cosh(x)=\frac12(e^x+e^{-x})$. If you compare this with the Euler formula for cosine, the connection should become apparent.

Comment: @Semiclassical Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

We show more: $\cos(\mathbb C)=\mathbb C$.

Proof: let $w_0 \in \mathbb C$. Then the equation $u^2-2uw_0+1=0$ has a solution $u_0$. Oberve that $u_0 \ne 0.$ It follows that

$$\frac{u_0+u_0^{-1}}{2}=w_0.$$

Furthermore we know that the equation $e^{iz}=u_0$ has a solution $z_0$. Hence

$$\frac{e^{iz_0}+e^{-iz_0}}{2}=w_0.$$

And therefore

$$\cos(z_0)=w_0.$$